# Loseless Join: if one has more information or has to do a projection before joining

Tags: sql, join

is it consider a loseless join the original table `R(ABCD)` and then we table `R1(ABC)` and `R2(BCD)`. We verifed that ABC are keys in `R1, but only C is a key in`R2`.  Is it a loseless join if we join R1 and R2 via C?  Or is it not a loseless join because we would need to do a projection of R2(CD) before we join.

For example

```
R1             R2
a1, b1, c1     b2, c1, d1
```

Join via C then result is

```
a1, b1, c1, d1
a1, b2, c1, d1
```

We have more information than we started out with!  Thus, I'm not sure if this would be considered a loseless join or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
R1(ABC), R2(BCD)

R1 ∩ R2 = BC
R1 - R2 = A
```

--> if `A->BC` is in function dependencies => lossless

Check

```
R2 - R1 = D
```

--> if `D->BC` is in function dependencies => lossless